# Facebook IOS login with the installed Facebook application Swift

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-login

Im trying to add Facebook login to my app.
i have got that part working the only thing i don't like is the popup box with login.

Is there a way to login with Facebook with the Facebook application?

i searched the internet for what i have at this moment:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQiC7.png

And what i want:http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2013/04/iphone-write1.png

This is the code im using now.

```
  FBSession.openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "email", "user_friends","user_photos","user_birthday","user_location"], allowLoginUI: true,completionHandler: {(session, state, error) -> Void in
        self.sessionStateChanged(session, state: state, error: error)
        var loginBool = FBSession.activeSession().isOpen
        if(loginBool == true){
            let vc : UIViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerLoggedInProfile") as UIViewController;
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

    } )
```

Comment: Use "Parse" framework to login with Facebook with the Facebook application.

Comment: Parse is a framework and it is also owned by Facebook. It provide objects for Facebook SDK login, sharing etc. You can go to www.parse.com and read the documentation about it.

Comment: If you like my answer, please rate it. :)

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this without parse( seeing parse costs money)

Comment: I do not know the other way. This is the most recommended way and it do not cost too much money. 30 requests per second are free.

Comment: But how do you do it in Parse i can't find it in the documentation

Comment: https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-ios

Comment: well thats not the one with the native dialog